# Test::Simple to check for file exists

Tags: perl, unit-testing

Is there a way to use test::simple to check if a file exists?  I'm fairly new with perl and I read all of test::tutorial, simple.  I'm assuming I need to make a sub in a module, but can I just add in regular perl code to check for a file?  If so how do I call it from the testing file?

Sorry I have no code as I really don't get this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
$filename = '/path/to/your/file.doc';
 if (-e $filename) {
 print "File Exists!";
 }
```

To see if the file is allowed to be read, written to, or executed we can use these instead of `-e` above:

```
Readable: -r
Writable: -w
Executable: -x
```

Using Test::Simple

```
use Test::Simple tests => 1;
my $filename='/path/to/your/file.doc';

ok(checkfile($file)==1,'File found');

sub checkfile{
    if (-e $_[0]) { return 1;}
    else { return 0; }
}
```

OR

```
use Test::Simple tests => 1;
my $filename='/path/to/your/file.doc';

ok(-e $filename,'File found');
```

Comment: You don't even need to do it in a subroutine, you can just do it like this: `ok(-e $file, "file exists");`

Comment: The purpose of a subroutine is to be able to use it for checking multiple files by just calling the subroutine with the file name that I want to check. Just a fancy way.

Answer (score 1):

[Test::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::File) seems well suited for this need.

```
use Test::File;
file_exists_ok $filename, "Check the file exists";
```